# How to make an age calculator app with UIPickerView?

Tags: xcode, uipickerview, calculator

I'm trying to make an age calculator app with UIPickerView. I have the code to do the calculations, but how do I insert them to work with a UIPickerView?
The age calculation code is in an NSString 
- (NSString *)age:(NSDate *)dateOfBirth

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best place for learning how to accomplish that would be in apple's docs. Here is the link for the doc's. it also has 5 sample codes links inside it that is going to be of a great help to you. Here s the link:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html